# precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, bundle

I'm having some problems, my rails app is not deploying successfully because of a precompile error

```
Invalid CSS after "c": expected "{", was "}"
(in /Users/johndoe/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):5567
```

any ideas on how to solve this or how I can find the exact line that is causing the error?

Comment: That's a pretty big CSS file with at least 5567 lines...

Comment: Share the file so it can be looked at. It looks like a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally typed a c next to a closing curly bracket.  Do a find with `c}` and you'll catch it.